# NoneType object is not iterable python cisco meraki

Tags: python-3.x

Tried to do a script that will pull all the clients on my meraki organization. An error occurred I think the file that I want to iterate cant be read by my code.

Thanks,

I tried changing the shard to specific tried installing modules that i think required but still same error

```
import sys, getopt, requests, json, time, datetime, os, sqlite3

#SECTION: GLOBAL VARIABLES: MODIFY TO CHANGE SCRIPT BEHAVIOUR

API_EXEC_DELAY              = 0.21 #Used in merakirequestthrottler() to avoid hitting dashboard API max request rate

#connect and read timeouts for the Requests module in seconds
REQUESTS_CONNECT_TIMEOUT    = 90
REQUESTS_READ_TIMEOUT       = 90

#SECTION: GLOBAL VARIABLES AND CLASSES: DO NOT MODIFY

LAST_MERAKI_REQUEST         = datetime.datetime.now()   #used by merakirequestthrottler()
ARG_APIKEY                  = '' #DO NOT STATICALLY SET YOUR API KEY HERE
ARG_ORGNAME                 = '' #DO NOT STATICALLY SET YOUR ORGANIZATION NAME HERE
ORG_LIST                    = None #list of organizations, networks and MRs the used API key has access to
DEVICE_DB                   = None #SQLite3 database of all network devices
MAX_CLIENT_TIMESPAN         = 2592000 #maximum timespan GET clients Dashboard API call supports

class c_Net:
    def __init__(self):
        id          = ''
        name        = ''
        shard       = 'n132.meraki.com'
        devices     = []

class c_Organization:
    def __init__(self):
        id          = ''
        name        = ''
        shard       = 'n132.meraki.com'
        nets        = []


#SECTION: General use functions

def merakirequestthrottler():
    #makes sure there is enough time between API requests to Dashboard not to hit shaper
    global LAST_MERAKI_REQUEST

    if (datetime.datetime.now()-LAST_MERAKI_REQUEST).total_seconds() < (API_EXEC_DELAY):
        time.sleep(API_EXEC_DELAY)

    LAST_MERAKI_REQUEST = datetime.datetime.now()
    return

def printhelp():
    print(readMe)


#SECTION: Meraki Dashboard API communication functions

def getInventory(p_org):
    #returns a list of all networks in an organization

    merakirequestthrottler()
    try:
        r = requests.get('https://%s/api/v0/organizations/%s/inventory' % (p_org.shard, p_org.id), headers={'X-Cisco-Meraki-API-Key': ARG_APIKEY, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, timeout=(REQUESTS_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, REQUESTS_READ_TIMEOUT) )
    except:
        print('ERROR 01: Unable to contact Meraki cloud')
        return(None)

    if r.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
        return(None)

    return(r.json())


def getNetworks(p_org):
    #returns a list of all networks in an organization

    merakirequestthrottler()
    try:
        r = requests.get('https://%s/api/v0/organizations/%s/networks' % (p_org.shard, p_org.id), headers={'X-Cisco-Meraki-API-Key': ARG_APIKEY, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, timeout=(REQUESTS_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, REQUESTS_READ_TIMEOUT) )
    except:
        print('ERROR 07: Unable to contact Meraki cloud')
        return(None)

    if r.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
        return(None)

    return(r.json())


def getOrgs():
    #returns the organizations' list for a specified admin, with filters applied

    merakirequestthrottler()
    try:
        r = requests.get('https://n132.meraki.com/api/v0/organizations', headers={'X-Cisco-Meraki-API-Key': ARG_APIKEY, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, timeout=(REQUESTS_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, REQUESTS_READ_TIMEOUT) )
    except:
        print('ERROR 02: Unable to contact Meraki cloud')
        return(None)

    if r.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
        return(None)

    rjson = r.json()
    orglist = []
    listlen = -1

    if ARG_ORGNAME.lower() == '/all':
        for org in rjson:
            orglist.append(c_Organization())
            listlen += 1
            orglist[listlen].id     = org['id']
            orglist[listlen].name   = org['name']
    else:
        for org in rjson:
            if org['name'] == ARG_ORGNAME:
                orglist.append(c_Organization())
                listlen += 1
                orglist[listlen].id     = org['id']
                orglist[listlen].name   = org['name']

    return(orglist)


def getShardHost(p_org):
    #Looks up shard URL for a specific org. Use this URL instead of 'api.meraki.com'
    # when making API calls with API accounts that can access multiple orgs.
    #On failure returns None

    merakirequestthrottler()
    try:
        r = requests.get('https://n132.meraki.com/api/v0/organizations/%s/snmp' % p_org.id, headers={'X-Cisco-Meraki-API-Key': ARG_APIKEY, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, timeout=(REQUESTS_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, REQUESTS_READ_TIMEOUT) )
    except:
        print('ERROR 03: Unable to contact Meraki cloud')
        return None

    if r.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
        return None

    rjson = r.json()

    return(rjson['hostname'])


def refreshOrgList():
    global ORG_LIST
    global DEVICE_DB

    print('INFO: Starting org list refresh at %s...' % datetime.datetime.now())

    flag_firstorg = True
    orglist = getOrgs()

    if not orglist is None:
        for org in orglist:
            print('INFO: Processing org "%s"' % org.name)

            org.shard = 'n132.meraki.com'
            orgshard = getShardHost(org)
            if not orgshard is None:
                org.shard = orgshard
            netlist = getNetworks(org)
            devlist = getInventory(org)

            if not devlist is None and not netlist is None:

                DEVICE_DB = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
                dbcursor = DEVICE_DB.cursor()
                dbcursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE devices (serial text, name text, networkId text, mac text, type text, model text)''')
                dbcursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE ouis (oui text)''')
                DEVICE_DB.commit()

                for device in devlist:
                    if not device['networkId'] is None:
                        devType = 'merakiDevice'
                        if device['model'][:2] in ['MR','MS','MX','Z1','Z3']:
                            devType = 'merakiNetworkDevice'
                        dbcursor.execute('''INSERT INTO devices VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)''', (device['serial'],device['name'],device['networkId'],device['mac'],devType,device['model']))
                        dbcursor.execute('''INSERT INTO ouis VALUES (?)''', (device['mac'][:8],))
                DEVICE_DB.commit()   

                flag_firstnet = True

                for net in netlist:
                    if net['type'] != 'systems manager': #ignore systems manager nets
                        dbcursor.execute('''SELECT serial, name, model FROM devices WHERE networkId = ? AND type = ?''', (net['id'],'merakiNetworkDevice'))

                        devicesofnet = dbcursor.fetchall()

                        if len(devicesofnet) > 0: #network has MR, MS, MX, Zx
                            if flag_firstnet:
                                if flag_firstorg:
                                    ORG_LIST = []
                                    lastorg = -1
                                    flag_firstorg = False

                                ORG_LIST.append(org)
                                lastorg += 1
                                lastnet = -1
                                ORG_LIST[lastorg].nets = []

                                flag_firstnet = False

                            ORG_LIST[lastorg].nets.append(c_Net())
                            lastnet += 1
                            ORG_LIST[lastorg].nets[lastnet].id      = net['id']
                            ORG_LIST[lastorg].nets[lastnet].name    = net['name']
                            ORG_LIST[lastorg].nets[lastnet].shard   = org.shard
                            ORG_LIST[lastorg].nets[lastnet].devices = []

                            for device in devicesofnet:
                                ORG_LIST[lastorg].nets[lastnet].devices.append(device)

    LAST_ORGLIST_REFRESH = datetime.datetime.now()      
    print('INFO: Refresh complete at %s' % LAST_ORGLIST_REFRESH)

    return None


def getclientlist(p_shardhost, p_serial, p_timespan):

    merakirequestthrottler()
    try:
        r = requests.get('https://%s/api/v0/devices/%s/clients?timespan=%s' % (p_shardhost, p_serial, p_timespan), headers={'X-Cisco-Meraki-API-Key': ARG_APIKEY, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, timeout=(REQUESTS_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, REQUESTS_READ_TIMEOUT) )
    except:
        print('ERROR 04: Unable to contact Meraki cloud')
        return(None)

    if r.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
        return(None)

    return(r.json())  


#SECTION: main

def main(argv):
    global ARG_APIKEY
    global ARG_ORGNAME

    #initialize command line arguments
    ARG_APIKEY      = ''
    ARG_ORGNAME     = ''
    arg_numresults  = ''
    arg_mode        = ''
    arg_filter      = ''    

    #get command line arguments
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, 'hk:o:m:')
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        printhelp()
        sys.exit(2)

    for opt, arg in opts:
        if   opt == '-h':
            printhelp()
            sys.exit()
        elif opt == '-k':
            ARG_APIKEY      = arg
        elif opt == '-o':
            ARG_ORGNAME     = arg
        elif opt == '-m':
            arg_mode        = arg

    #check that all mandatory arguments have been given
    if ARG_APIKEY == '':
        printhelp()
        sys.exit(2)        

    #set defaults for empty command line arguments
    if ARG_ORGNAME == '':
        ARG_ORGNAME = '/all'

    refreshOrgList()

    if ORG_LIST is None or DEVICE_DB is None:
        print('ERROR 05: No organizations with network devices access points for the specified API key')
        sys.exit(2)

    DEVcursor   = DEVICE_DB.cursor()

    for org in ORG_LIST:
        flag_firstNet = True
        orgClientList = []
        reportFileName = 'clients_' + org.name + '_' + str(datetime.datetime.now()).replace(':','.') + '.csv'
        print ('INFO: Processing org "%s"' % org.name)
        for net in org.nets:
            print ('INFO: Processing net "%s"' % net.name)
            for dev in net.devices:
                clients = getclientlist(org.shard, dev[0], MAX_CLIENT_TIMESPAN)
                for client in clients:
                    DEVcursor.execute('''SELECT oui FROM ouis WHERE oui = ?''', (client['mac'][:8],))
                    matchingMerakiOuis = DEVcursor.fetchall()
                    if len(matchingMerakiOuis) == 0: #client device is not, in fact, a Meraki device neighbour
                        if flag_firstNet:
                            flag_firstNet = False
                            print('INFO: Creating file "' + reportFileName + '"')
                            try:
                                f = open(reportFileName, 'w')
                                f.write('id,mac,description,mdnsName,dhcpHostname,ip,vlan,switchport,usageKBSentToClient,usageKBRecvFromClient,networkId,networkName,reportedByDevSerial,reportedByDevName,reportedByDevModel\n')
                            except:
                                print('ERROR 06: Unable to open file "' + reportFileName + '" for writing')
                                sys.exit(2)

                        try:
                            f.write(str(client['id']) + ',' +
                                    str(client['mac']) + ',' +
                                    str(client['description']) + ',' +
                                    str(client['mdnsName']) + ',' +
                                    str(client['dhcpHostname']) + ',' +
                                    str(client['ip']) + ',' +
                                    str(client['vlan']) + ',' +
                                    str(client['switchport']) + ',' +
                                    str(int(client['usage']['sent'])) + ',' +
                                    str(int(client['usage']['recv'])) + ',' +
                                    str(net.id) + ',' +
                                    str(net.name) + ',' +
                                    str(dev[0]) + ',' +
                                    str(dev[1]) + ',' +
                                    str(dev[2]) + '\n' )
                        except:
                            print('ERROR 08: Unable to write to file "' + reportFileName + '"')
                            sys.exit(2)


    DEVICE_DB.close()

    try:
        f.close()
    except:
        print ('INFO: Unable to close file (not open?)')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "orgsclientcsv.py", line 351, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "orgsclientcsv.py", line 308, in main
    for client in clients:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

The result should be an csv file that will give me list of phones mac address serial number manufacturer but the actual output is only phones mac address like Iphone